# Action bar exception when I pressed first item

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar

I have writed one action bar.It's too simple. When I click someone, they go to the same activity. There are only different between on the intent messages. I did as I always do. My problem is, when I click on first item gives me an exception but second one is purely working. What I did wrong? How can I fix it?

My purpose is : I want to send a message this activity at my action bar"s items. İf message 123 I am going to do anything but if other item has clicked I do different thing.I just want to find which item is clicked by users.

Atolye_action_bar.class :

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.muddzdev.styleabletoastlibrary.StyleableToast;

public class Atolyem_action_bar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_atolyem_action_bar);





        Bundle exras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = exras.getString("gzsz");
        String value_anlamsız_ıntent_message = exras.getString("anlamsız");


        if (value.equals("123")){
            new StyleableToast
                    .Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .text("Doğru")
                    .textColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
                    .show();


        }




    }
}
```

shape of taking message :

```
Bundle yeni = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value_anlamsız_ıntent_message = yeni.getString("anlamsız");


        Bundle exras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = exras.getString("gzsz");


// İt is true.
        if (value != null && value.equals("123")){
            new StyleableToast
                    .Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .text("Doğru")
                    .textColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
                    .show();


        }
// it is not working.
        if (value_anlamsız_ıntent_message != null && value_anlamsız_ıntent_message.equals("selam")){

            new StyleableToast
                    .Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .text("yalan")
                    .textColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
                    .show();






        }
```

Here is my items :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Sadace Anlamsız kelimeler"
        android:id="@+id/anlamsız_atolyem"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        />
    <item android:title="Sadace Gözsüz kelimeler"
        android:id="@+id/gözsüz_atolyem"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="100"/>
</menu>
```

And my code :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.atolyem_for,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id ==R.id.anlamsız_atolyem) {   
            anlamsız();
            return true;
        }

        if (id ==R.id.gözsüz_atolyem  ){
            gzsz(); return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void gzsz() {
        String gzsz = "123";

        Intent gzsz_intent = new Intent(Atolyem.this, Atolyem_action_bar.class);
        gzsz_intent.putExtra( "gzsz",gzsz );
        startActivity(gzsz_intent);
    }

    private void anlamsız() {
        String anlamsiz = "selam";

        Intent anlamsız_intent = new Intent(Atolyem.this, Atolyem_action_bar.class);
         anlamsız_intent.putExtra( "anlamsiz",anlamsiz);
         startActivity(anlamsız_intent);
    }
```

Here is my exception :

```
03-07 23:44:24.717 3654-3654/something.about.berkay.kkk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: something.about.berkay.kkk, PID: 3654
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{something.about.berkay.kkk/something.about.berkay.kkk.Atolyem_action_bar}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at something.about.berkay.kkk.Atolyem_action_bar.onCreate(Atolyem_action_bar.java:25)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I have editted my question.

Comment: What is the error? You said it gives you an exception.

Comment: Sorry. I approved edit suggestion when I put my exception.You can see now.

Comment: Could you see any mistake in my code ?

Comment: Looks like it's happening in Atolyem_action_bar. Can you post that class?

Comment: sure.Wait a minute.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is null if no extra with key "gzsz" is set. Perform a null check before calling equals like this:

```
if (value != null && value.equals("123")){
...
```

Comment: Yes ,your code has worked.Thanks for your helping. It passing to other activity. But now there is one more different problem about message intent.First message corrently work but second(if statement)   is not working.By the way ; what is the reason why it has been like.

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am doing an action bar.This action bar has two items.When I click these items , they send to different messages to Atolyem_action_bar.class. And I am going to design  my Atolyem_action_bar.layout by these messages.

Comment: Hmm that should work. What is false? Then null check or the equals check?